# Can only insert one elem in SQLite in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite

I try to do a Todolist in C#

I full a pannel with textbox.
I use SQLite. I create a file in the current directory.
i have simple table with int  and  VARCHAR.
But i can write only on line.
When i restart i can't remplace this line. I need to delete SQLite file.

thanks

the start

```
namespace Todolist
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
                if (!File.Exists("MaBaseDeDonnees.sqlite"))SQLiteConnection.CreateFile("MaBaseDeDonnees.sqlite");
                SQLiteConnection maConnexion;
                var ConnectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|MaBaseDeDonnees.sqlite";
                maConnexion = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
                maConnexion.Open();
                var sql = "create table IF NOT EXISTS todo (nb INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , data VARCHAR(255))";
                var commande = new SQLiteCommand(sql, maConnexion);
                commande.ExecuteNonQuery();
                sql = "insert into todo (data) values ('text1')";
                sql = "insert into todo (data) values ('text2')";
                commande = new SQLiteCommand(sql, maConnexion);
                commande.ExecuteNonQuery();
                maConnexion.Close();
                display_todo();
            }
```

the display:

```
private void display_todo()
{
    var ConnectionString = "Data Source=|DataDirectory|MaBaseDeDonnees.sqlite";
    var maConnexion = new SQLiteConnection(ConnectionString);
    maConnexion.Open();
    var sql = "select * from todo";
    var commande = new SQLiteCommand(sql, maConnexion);

    var reader = commande.ExecuteReader();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        var textBox1 = new TextBox();
        textBox1.Location = new Point(10, 10);
        textBox1.Text = (string) reader["data"];
        textBox1.Size = new Size(200, 30);
        todoPannel.Controls.Add(textBox1);
    }
    maConnexion.Close();
```

only text2 is display

sorry edit:

```
sql = "insert into todo (data) values ('text1')";
commande = new SQLiteCommand(sql, maConnexion);
commande.ExecuteNonQuery();
String sql1 = "insert into todo (data) values ('text2')";
commande = new SQLiteCommand(sql1, maConnexion);
commande.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

i have always the error

Comment: Could you post schema of your `data` table?

Comment: sorry i I don't know what to do. 
id do :create table IF NOT EXISTS todo (nb INTEGER PRIMARY KEY , data VARCHAR(255))

Comment: Try adding `AUTOINCREMENT`to you primary key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same variable (`sql`) to store 2 different inserts:

```
sql = "insert into todo (data) values ('text1')";
sql = "insert into todo (data) values ('text2')";
```

Name them differently(`sql` and `sql1`) and execute the insert command twice.

Comment: My display is wrong i have my data when i test to print on the console thanks everyone

Answer (score 1):

You are overwriting the SQL value:

```
 sql = "insert into todo (data) values ('text1')";
 sql = "insert into todo (data) values ('text2')";
```

The second statement will overwrite the previous value, hence only the last one is executed.

You can either execute multiple statements one by one, or you can join the two statements and then execute them like:

```
 sql = "insert into todo (data) values ('text1');insert into todo (data) values ('text2')";
```

Answer (score 0):

that is because you reassign the command text to `sql` variable. Try:

```
sql = "insert into todo (data) values ('text1')";
sql2 = "insert into todo (data) values ('text2')";
commande = new SQLiteCommand(sql, maConnexion);
commande.ExecuteNonQuery();
commande2 = new SQLiteCommand(sql2, maConnexion);
commande2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```